# closesocket() executing long time

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, network-programming

I create an application for testing; I use Platinum library for realization of UPnP protocol and I was faced with problem: process don't finished after closing window and ignore my attempts to kill it using Task Manager. I can view this ghost of my application next 1-10 minutes.

After debugging I can say that problem in the network code - Platinum code create 4 threads for receiving UDP packets on network interface. This threads don't closed when I destroy all library objects and they closing after all another threads. Problem in destructor of NPT_BsdSocketFd - when it call closesocket() execution will not returned from this function :(
Every thread have his own socket for receiving.

```
~NPT_BsdSocketFd() {
    if (m_Cancellable) {
        if (!NPT_BSD_SOCKET_IS_INVALID(m_CancelFds[0])) closesocket(m_CancelFds[0]);
        if (!NPT_BSD_SOCKET_IS_INVALID(m_CancelFds[1])) closesocket(m_CancelFds[1]);
    }
    closesocket(m_SocketFd);  //problem here...
}
```

Does anyone know why closesocket() executing such long time?

Comment: Any chance this is an output socket, and you have just sent some large amount of data through it, that hasn't been received/ack'd by the other end?

Comment: I can't guarantee it yet, but I think that this is possible. But it is UDP socket and there is no need in acknowledgements from other end.

Comment: Ah, so with UDP, it would still wait until all the data is flushed out of the user-space into the kernel, but once that is done, it should be possible to close the socket. However, that's the only reasonable reason why you would get such a long closing time (other than bugs in the implementation of kernel & drivers, of course)

Comment: After testing I can say that this bug exist only on my pc, under windows. On all other PCs in our laboratory program work correctly. Also, when I start it on my computer under linux it was finished without any problems. It's looks like a problem in the drivers.

Comment: Or AntiVirus software acting up... ;)